AWK search for multiple patterns in a file
I'm trying to figure out how to implement a multiple patterns "AND" search in a file. Basically the application should do something only when ALL of the 3 patterns are present in /var/log/messages
This will work but use "OR":
awk '/writeback error on sector/ || /blk_update_request: I\/O error/ || /xfs_do_force_shutdown/' /var/log/messages

This apparently doesn't work:
awk '/writeback error on sector/ && /blk_update_request: I\/O error/ && /xfs_do_force_shutdown/' /var/log/messages

What I need is something like:

Check /var/log/messages
If ALL 3 patterns are present in messages then do something

If possible using grep where I can use "-f patterns" to use external file where user can add other patterns
Could someone please advice?
Thank you
Lucas

Do you want to search for patters to be present in entire file or in one line?

I want to search in a whole file /var/log/messages

Similar: grep'ping files for multiple strings (not necessarily on the same line)

When you say "patterns" what do you actually mean - regular expressions or literal strings?

if 
  awk '
    !a && /writeback error on sector/      {a=1}
    !b && /blk_update_request: I\/O error/ {b=1}
    !c && /xfs_do_force_shutdown/          {c=1}
    success = a + b + c == 3 {exit}
    END {if (!success) exit 1}' /var/log/messages
then
  echo 'All 3 found, not necessarily on the same lines.'
fi

Or for the list of regexps to be read from a file (here assumed to be non-empty¹):
if
  awk '
    !patterns_read {patterns[$0]; next}
    {
      for (pattern in patterns)
        if ($0 ~ pattern) {
          delete patterns[pattern]
          if (success = length(patterns) == 0) exit
        }
    }
    END {if (!success) exit 1}
  ' /path/to/list-of-patterns patterns_read=1 /var/log/messages
then
  echo 'All patterns found.'
fi

(untested).
Note the patterns are a variant of extended regular expressions, similar to those of grep -E.

¹ if the pattern file is empty, it will go through the whole input, checking for nothing and report false in the end.

Your code is testing for all 3 regexps matching in one record but by default awk treats each input line as a separate record so one option would be to have awk treat the whole input file as a record, e.g. using GNU awk for multi-char RS:
awk -v RS='^$' '/writeback error on sector/ && /blk_update_request: I\/O error/ && /xfs_do_force_shutdown/' /var/log/messages

or any awk:
awk '{r=r $0 RS} END{$0=r; if (/writeback error on sector/ && /blk_update_request: I\/O error/ && /xfs_do_force_shutdown/) print}' /var/log/messages

I see you added:

If possible using grep where I can use "-f patterns" to use external file where user can add other patterns

to your question. If you aren't entirely in control of the "patterns" your script is using, as would be the case if you're reading them from a file, then it becomes much more important for you to decide (and tell us) what you mean by "patterns", i.e. do you mean regexps or strings and do you mean literal or partial and can they overlap, etc., etc. as reading a string that contains regexp metachars like . or *, for example, needs to be sanitized if you really want to treat it as a literal string. See how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern then post a new question about that.

Thanks, even if I prefer to use the above solution who will read from external file.

Since you already accepted an answer to the question you asked, you should ask a new question about how to read "patterns" from a file as the right answer depends on what you mean by "patterns" since they are no longer part of the script that you write. See the info I just added to the bottom of my answer.
